# How to override AdvancedCustomDrawItem - TreeView

Tags: delphi

i'm trying to override AdvancedCustomDrawItem Method since i want to make my owner TreeView 
this is my attempt :

```
type TTreeView=class (Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeView )
  protected
  procedure AdvancedCustomDrawItem(
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage;
  var PaintImages, DefaultDraw: Boolean);override;

 end;
```

but i got this error :
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(10): E2137 Method 'AdvancedCustomDrawItem' not found in base class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot override that method because it doesn't exist. The `OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem` event is fired from `CustomDrawItem` which you can override. It is declared like this in `TCustomTreeView`:

```
function CustomDrawItem(Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState;
  Stage: TCustomDrawStage; var PaintImages: Boolean): Boolean; virtual;
```

The base implementation fires both `OnCustomDrawItem` and `OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem` events.

If you want to get anywhere with this endeavour you'll need to consult the source code for this control.